# Android Studio(FacebookSDK) - onCreateView not being called

Tags: java, android

AS the title states my onCreateView doesn't get called. My objective is to get the Facebook login to work. At current state it just buffers and returns to the same state. It does not change to the "Logout" state.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.frederik.snapsule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton login;
    TextView info;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    //Creating and initializing the feature(Code from Facebook install guide)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); //Calls for the facebook feature
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    }

    public View onCreateView (
            LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_main, container, false);

        login = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

        // Callback registration
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

I believe it should work as a fragment in some sort, but that's an area new to me, so detailed answers please =)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace you MainActivity code with this one :

```
    package com.example.frederik.snapsule;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LoginButton login;
    TextView info;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    //Creating and initializing the feature(Code from Facebook install guide)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); //Calls for the facebook feature
         callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.content_main);

         login = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        login.setReadPermissions("user_friends");

        // Callback registration
        login.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                // App code
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                // App code
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: That fixed it somewhat, however, my button still just logs me in then returns me to the "log in with facebook" button. I was told it should change to Logout

Comment: To know what is being done actually ,You need to put Toast inside onSuccess(),onCancel() . So that you can see what is happening .

Comment: To do logout you can use LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

Comment: Seems like it doesn't suceed when logging in then. Nothing changes atleast

Answer (score 0):

`Activity` does not have a method called `onCreateView()`, thus the framework will not call it. If you need to initialize your UI, use `onCreate()` instead, because `onCreateView()` is for `Fragment`s.

Comment: I am trying to get the button working as a fragment, but how do I assign this?